# Error "disk quota exceeded" when pull on git

Tags: git, gitlab

Im already update my project and I have error when I pull a new update project on git.
this eror on this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuTnZ.png).
i need solution. 
thanks before

Comment: This has nothing to do with git. Somebody (possibly the server administrator) added a disk space limitation for your user (aka quota) to the directory you want to store your data in. You are using more space than the system allows.

Comment: oke. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your user isn't allowed to write any more files to this disk. Free up some disk space by deleting some files and try again. Or talk to your sysadmin about increasing your quota.